# How to achieve bidirectional DC-AC power flow with a Grid-tied Inverter?

Tags: inverter

Question:  How can I achieve DC-AC bi-directional energy flow control of a grid-tied inverter?

I want to control the bidirectional DC-AC power flow of a 3-phase grid tied inverter that I am developing. The inverter should perform DC-AC as well as AC-DC action so that I can either charge a battery from the grid, or transfer energy from the battery to the grid.

I have attached the topology I am currently working with.
This shows the overall system but the question is focused on the DC_AC bidirectional aspects.

[image: Grid tied Inverter]

**_________________________________________________**

**Background information:**

Here is the short description of the steps I completed.

- I used Clarke and Park transformation to implement Phase locked loop(PLL).
- Implemented Space Vector modulation for PWM generation.
- Completed synchronization with the grid.
- Now testing power flow segment
- I used dsPIC33fj32mc202 microcontroller for implementing the inverter. Really it was a very hectic journey for me as I have to learn DSP assembly instruction of the microcontroller for fast calculating all the algorithm related to grid-tied inverter.

Now I want to control the bidirectional DC-AC energy flow.
I want to charge battery sometimes. I studied a lot of papers. But could not recover the information about how to change the power flow direction.

Comment: This looks like homework / an assignment. If it is you should say so. Regardless, you need to explain your understanding of the question.

Comment: I am currently working on the inverter. I have completed the Grid sync section(DC-AC) but stuck on AC-DC power flow control. I used dspic33fj32mc202 microntroller

Comment: There should be many papers on this on web, and I am not expert in the practicalities, but energy transfer can be controlled by altering the phase angle between grid and the inverter. As you transfer from lead to lag the energy transfer direction changes and the rate of transfer can be adjusted by changing phase angle.

Comment: Most of the research paper are on single direction(DC-AC or AC-DC). I cannot agree with  by controlling phase angle  changes power flow direction.

Comment: You may need to alter your question - and will in any case need to do so if you want it re-opened. You asked "How can I achieve the bi-directional power flow control of grid-tied inverter?" -> my answer was correct with respect to the grid tied aspect involving AC-AC and that is how most people would understand your question (IMHO). If  you were asking about DC-AC bidirectionality and not AC-AC it may be a good idea to make that clear. IF that is your main question then a question focused on that aspect may be better received.

Comment: There appears to be a large amount on web. [THIS](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Luiz_Ribeiro5/publication/269101426_Bidirectional_DC-AC_converter_for_isolated_microgrids_with_voltage_unbalance_reduction_capabilities/links/551918b80cf2d70ee27b8344/Bidirectional-DC-AC-converter-for-isolated-microgrids-with-voltage-unbalance-reduction-capabilities.pdf) free access paper - "Bidirectional DC-AC Converter for Isolated Microgrids
with Voltage Unbalance Reduction Capabilities" looks a good fit. |

Comment: [THIS](https://www.google.co.nz/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNT2z2eFLi8IEfbdg4T9EBXNJwFLFw%3A1572051755526&source=hp&ei=K5uzXebHHYS0vwTM3IbgDA&q=bidirectional+dc+ac+converter&oq=bidirectional+dc+ac+converter&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30l9.3249.12377..15154...2.0..0.247.5293.0j30j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i39j0i131j0i67j0i20i263j0i67i70i249.0-fqEpRTYOU&ved=0ahUKEwimidGT3bjlAhUE2o8KHUyuAcwQ4dUDCAY&uact=5) Garglabet search turms up heaps.

Comment: including [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6388692) and [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6954085) and [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sprac85/sprac85.pdf) is a complete solution using a TI mpu "Bidirectional DC-AC Solution For Solar Application
System, Based on the TMS320F28035 MCU" and [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a97b/492e7bce5e27d7ce5c750798b1b768eab96b.pdf) 236 pages of PhD tgesis and [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Grid-tie-isolated-bidirectional-DC-AC-AC-converter-Sayed-Suzuki/d15fb0ed46d1f19ce9247bda7c1a6bc3e64af98d)

Comment: ... and [Agh / Wow !](https://www.google.co.nz/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNRcEgQfvE2CnV7EuCeBT1kG0mWhSg:1572051771009&q=bidirectional+dc+ac+converter&tbm=isch&source=hp&sxsrf=ACYBGNRcEgQfvE2CnV7EuCeBT1kG0mWhSg:1572051771009&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPq4Sb3bjlAhXQ7XMBHW7jCqsQsAR6BAgMEAE&biw=3072&bih=1538) . Yes?

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: Why not narrow down the question to ONE key part, such as AC-DC bidirectional conversion and ask fo the question to then be reopened.

Comment: I just looked at the edit list - I think your original have a better idea of what you were doing BUT did not focus on the key question. I have edited the subject line. I think that (perhaps) restoring the original text as background information and then focusing on the bidirectional AC-DC question "may help".

Comment: @Dave Tweed - question 'reworked' to show OP's focused intention. Reopening recommended.

Comment: You have now looked at the site since the above comments and editing but have said nothing? Why is this? What do you expect to happen when you ask more questions if you do not help thos who try to help you to do so?

Comment: Hello @RussellMcMahon, Thanks for the cooperation. It was night here in my place. I read a lot of research papers alike you provided. most of the paper claims that they have done this and all these are the equations but do not explain how the achieved that in hardware.  Btw I am looking into all your links. Thanks.

Comment: Shuvangkar - The TI application note provides full code for their processor. In section 5.1 on page 12 of the app note they provide a brief but useful explanation complete with vector diagram of 4 cases - DC to AC, AC to DC, and leading and lagging reactive power cases. That seems exactly what you wanted to know about.  || The PhD thesis is liable to provide the depth you need. |